# azure data factory - creating new column from another table and multiple criterion

Tags: azure-data-factory

Using Azure Data Factory, I am looking to bring in a csv file from blob storage, transform data a bit, then save to azure sql.  From the tutorials I am reviewing this looks pretty straight forward.  The complication comes in next step I am looking to accomplish...

source file: 20,000 rows, 100 columns

destination sql: 20,000 rows, 101 columns

I would like to add a new column.  The old way I did this was an azure function written in c#, but now I'd like to accomplish this in data factory.

Looks like 'derived column' can add a column in data factory, but my process is a bit more complicated.  when looking at a particular row in source, using 3 columns, I need to lookup from another sql table returning about 5 fields.  Then using those fields with other fields from the original row I need to do things including multiple if/thens, some switch statements and things like that.

Is there a better way to do this?  I was trying to stay away from stored procedures.  My goal is to use the azure approach of a process like this.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I was thinking this should be done during the 'copy data' section of pipeline but if it needs to be done afterwards in a different azure feature I am fine with that.  Whatever is best practice.

Comment: You can use **dataflow transformations** in ADF to do this.

Comment: Can you add sample input output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dataflow transformations as per your logics.

> when looking at a particular row in source, using 3 columns, I need to lookup from another sql table returning about 5 fields

[Join transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join) in the dataflow might work for this scenario. Take your original table and lookup table as two sources and give the 3 columns as join columns. You can give the join type as per your requirement.

[image]

After join, for multiple conditions, you can use [conditional split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-conditional-split) transformation. Give your conditions here and data will split.

[image]

Or, you can directly use [`iif()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#iif) or [`case()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#case) functions in the Dataflow expression. Take a derived column transformation and use these in the expression builder.

[image]

Go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions) to know about other functions in Dataflow expression.

Comment: thank you.  so just so I am clear, I can use the JOIN transformation, and lets say for example that join brings in 5 new fields... I can use those fields and the original row data in the next step, the expression builder?

Comment: Rows filtered based on the join will be available in next transformation.